# Simplifying multiplies of sums into a single double sum

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, expression-manipulation

I have the following expression:

```
Sum[x^n, {n, 1, Infinity}]*Sum[Log[m, x], {m, 2, Infinity}]
```

How can I Force Mathematica to write this expression in the following form?

```
Sum[x^n Log[m, x], {n, 1, Infinity}, {m, 2, Infinity}]
```

Comment: In the first expression, the first sum will evaluate symbolically unless held or inactivated; and the second sum contains a division by zero i.e. `Log[1, x]`

Comment: I edited the zero division problem. Thanks for that. @BobHanlon

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.
Let us introduce a rule:

```
rule = Inactive[Sum][a_., {k_, k0_: 1, m_}]*
    Inactive[Sum][b_., {q_, q0_: 1, n_}] :> 
   Inactive[Sum][Simplify[(a *b)], {k, k0, m}, {q, q0, n}];
```

In your expression let us first inactivate the sums:

```
expr = Inactive[Sum][x^n, {n, 1, Infinity}]*
  Inactive[Sum][Log[m, x], {m, 2, Infinity}]
```

[image]

Then:

```
expr1=expr /. rule
```

yields the following:

[image]

Now you can activate the result:

```
expr1//Activate
```

The result you will see on the screen is the same as I have shown above:

[image]

Have fun!